# Weight style on OL3

Tags: openlayers, geojson, style

I'm approaching to OL3 and I need to see different size for each element of this geojson file:
http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/data/world_cities.json
by using his "POP_RANK" value.
For example, for a "POP_RANK" = 2 I want a point with radius equal to 2 and for "POP_RANK"=5 I want a point with radius equal to 5.
I'm trynig to use this code:

```
var geojson_source = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_month.geojson';

var weight = geojson_source.getProperty('POP_RANK');

var style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: Math.pow(2, weight) / 3,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'orange', 
            width: 2
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
        })
    })
});
```

but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example demonstrates what you want to do: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml-earthquakes.html

Look at how the style function uses a feature's attribute for the radius calculation:

```
  var styleFunction = function(feature) {
    // 2012_Earthquakes_Mag5.kml stores the magnitude of each earthquake in a
    // standards-violating <magnitude> tag in each Placemark.  We extract it from
    // the Placemark's name instead.
    var name = feature.get('name');
    var magnitude = parseFloat(name.substr(2));
    var radius = 5 + 20 * (magnitude - 5);
    var style = styleCache[radius];
    if (!style) {
      style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: radius,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.4)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.2)',
            width: 1
          })
        })
      });
      styleCache[radius] = style;
    }
    return style;
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but when i use this

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your quick reply, but when i use this

```
    var geojson_source = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_month.geojson';


//stile
var styleCache = {};
var styleFunction = function(feature) {
    //var weight = feature.get('POP_RANK');
    var weight = 5;
    var radius = weight *10;
    var style = styleCache[radius];
    if (!style) {
        style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: radius,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.4)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.2)',
                    width: 1
                })
            })
        });
        styleCache[radius] = style;
    }
    return style;
};
```

it work only weight =5 not for var weight = feature.get('POP_RANK');, seems that js can't don't read geojson attribute